# Tablet Wacom Inutos Comic CTH 490 not recognized in system settings

Tags: drivers, system-settings, wacom

I recently have bought for myself a Wacom Inutos Comic CTH-490. It is reacting to touch and the standard config ist working. On the opposite side in the Ubuntu System Settings/Wacom Graphics Tablet, there is not tablet detected. As far as I read there are no known problems with this tablet. I am running Ubuntu 16.10.

Drivers `xf86-input-wacom` and `libwacom` were compiled by hand with guidance by http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page.

Following outputs are for the following commands:

`lsusb`: `Bus 001 Device 006: ID 056a:033c Wacom Co., Ltd`

`uname -r`: `4.8.0-41-generic`

`ls /dev/input/wacom/*`: `ls: Zugriff auf '/dev/input/wacom*' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden` (Says it ist not there)

`xsetwacom --list devices`:

```
Wacom Intuos PT S 2 Pen stylus      id: 12  type: STYLUS
Wacom Intuos PT S 2 Finger touch    id: 13  type: TOUCH     
Wacom Intuos PT S 2 Pad pad         id: 14  type: PAD
```

P.S.: When running `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:doctormo/wacom-plus` my Ubuntu `apt update` says: `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/doctormo/wacom-plus/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.`

Comment: ls /dev/input/wacom/ shouldn't show anything. This is the contents of my /dev/input with a wacom device attached $cd /dev/input$ ls
by-id    event1   event12  event2  event5  event8  mice    mouse2
by-path  event10  event13  event3  event6  event9  mouse0  mouse3
event0   event11  event14  event4  event7  js0     mouse1

Comment: Same is visible in my console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1575887

Comment: Well, I doubt that (I know that bug) because I have read posts here in askubuntu that got this specific tablet working. It may be another bug I doubt this also.

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/715030/wacom-intuos-cth-490-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-15-10?rq=1

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/688114/wacom-intuos-comic-cth-490-not-detected-by-system-settings-even-after-get-drive?rq=1

Comment: Does the tablet not work at all, or is this a problem with the control panel (system settings)? The 4.8 kernel should have native support for that tablet, and the tablet should work even if it doesn't appear in system settings.

Comment: Like I have written in the question it is only not visible in the system settings. Touch, Pen, etc. are working. GIMP can use it fully

Comment: The other questions you link to are for when the tablet doesn't work at all, those questions (though one mentions system settings) are about when the tablet doesn't work at all. The second one talks a lot about the system settings but says 'my Intuos Comic still does not work.'

Comment: When my english is good enough the second question is the same as my question, only this solution does not work.

Comment: The accepted answer to the second question involves updating the wacom kernel driver. Updating the kernel driver will not make the System Settings work.

Comment: Yeah I know this because I tried it already. But the question is why I am stuck here. I have libwacom-bin installed, so why is the tablet not shown in the settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55976/discussion-between-aaron-skomra-and-school-guy).